# Batch processing in python.

Tags: python, batch-processing, video-processing

I am just wondering, is there any way to process multiple videos in one go using a cluster may be? Specifically using python? For example, if I have 50+ videos in a folder and I have to analyze for movement related activity. Assuming I have a code written in python and I have to use that one particular code for the each video. What exactly I want is, instead of analyzing videos one by one (i.e., putting in loop) I need to analyze videos in parallel. Is there any way that I can implement the same?

Comment: You mean, other than running multiple copies of your application on the same computer?

Comment: Assuming that you can call your python script on the video `video1.mp4` like this `python script.py video1.mp4`, you can launch all the process at once with : `for i in *.mp4 ; do python script.py "$i" & done`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Sorry, I dint get your question properly. multiple copies of my application means running my scripts multiple times on the same computer? If yes, Correct I don't want to run my scripts multiple times, I want to run one script which will take care of dividing all the process.

Comment: @Till Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: Put all the processing logic in a function, and call the function in a loop - on each invocation give the function the video file name as an argument.

Comment: @boardrider I don't want to loop over. I want to parallelize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [multiprocessing](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html) or [threading](https://pymotw.com/2/threading/). The details can be a bit involved, and since you didn't give any in your question, suggesting the above links is about all I can help.